# Using custom icons, dp or wrap_content?

Tags: android, icons, size

I don't get it.

I want to create my own icon - a toggle icon - using Photoshop.

How big should this icon be?

should I write for example in xml for mdpi 48x48dp or wrap_content?

48dp looks so small, and 96dp looks so big..

What sizes shall I choose?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `Wrap_content` and for sizes look into [This](https://www.creativefreedom.co.uk/icon-designers-blog/android-4-1-icon-size-guide-made-simple/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dp` is Density Pixels which are virtual pixels, real pixels are different

if you defined `100dp` (density pixels) will be translated into real pixels on a variety of screens:

on `ldpi` screen

```
100.00dp = 75.00px
```

on `mdpi` screen

```
100.00dp = 100.00px
```

on `hdpi` screen

```
100.00dp = 150.00px
```

on `xhdpi` screen

```
100.00dp = 200.00px
```

so there's have to be four image resources with different values under the same name in the project(app).

There're two ways to To import these four images to support all four screens.

**First,** make 4 images in photoshop with the different pixels `200px`, `150px`, `100px`, `75px` these values depends on `100dp`, **they change if you change `100dp`**

**Second,** **(Best Approach)**. make just a `200px` image in photoshop and Download ( Android Drawable Importer plugin ) on android studio than use its ( Batch Drawable importer ) feature to import the `200px`

**Note** there are more that these four screens like Smart Watch(smaller than ldpi) and TV (larger than xhdpi), but these four are the commonly used

Comment: Thank u for this answer.. I appreciate it.

Comment: and thanks for the tipp u gave me :D with the drawable importer plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make same icon for different sizes like below:

```
36x36 (0.75x) for low-density : ldpi
48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density : mdpi
72x72 (1.5x) for high-density :hdpi
96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density : xhdpi
144x144 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density : xxhdpi
192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density : xxxhdpi
```

add these icon with same name in different drawable folder according to their density.